# Change background color in div, using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just wanted a button to change some colors.
For example I have the background in "wrap" div and some borders in other divs.

```
#wrap {

    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh;

    margin:0 auto;

    font: italic bold 15px arial, sans-serif;

    background-color: rgb(0, 14, 51);

    overflow-y: scroll;

    background-size: cover;

}
```

```
    #middleBarExtra{


        margin-top: 130px;

        height: 1px;
        width:100%;

        border: solid 5px rgb(200, 64, 235);

        border-radius: 30px;

}
```

How can I change the background color in "wrap" and the border color in "midlleBarExtra", with a function in javascript?

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
function changeColors(){
    
    document.getElementById("wrap").style.background = "white";

}
```

Comment: Can you attach your full snippet?

Comment: document.getElementById("wrap").style.background = "white"; - This is correct

Comment: How do you call changeColors() ?

Comment: Did you try document.getElementById("wrap").style.backgroundColor = "white" ?

Comment: i call in in the body:  <button onclick="changeColors()">change</button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change only styles, it's a better idea to add/remove classes instead of using completely js.

```js
function changeColors(){
    document.getElementById("wrap").classList.toggle("new-styles");
}
```

```css
#wrap {
   width:100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   margin:0 auto;
   background: rgb(0, 14, 51);
}
#middleBarExtra{
    margin-top: 130px;
    height: 1px;
    width:100%;
    border: solid 5px rgb(200, 64, 235);
    border-radius: 30px;
}
#wrap.new-styles {
   background: rgb(255,255,255);
}
.new-styles #middleBarExtra {
   border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeColors()">Change</button>

<div id="wrap">
   <div id="middleBarExtra"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("wrap").style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

Comment: Not working :/, might be something wrong with me calling it? <button onclick="changeColors()">change</button>

Comment: Is there an error message? Did you change "...style.background" to ...style.background**Color**"?